# Deleted Stock Dialer App, Not Receiving Call Notifications

Tags: root-access, calls

So, I have the BLU STUDIO 6.0 LTE and am rooted. I deleted the Stock Phone app, replaced it with Reactiv Dialer. I can make calls just fine. But I hear the ring when someone calls but no screen pops up for me to answer. Any apps that would give me third party notifications for PHONE CALLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to reinstall it, I'm afraid. If another app provided such a function, this would cause conflict and even possible device crashes.